# Calling Date(); object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get todays date using JS so I add a class to highlight opening hours for the current day.

HTML

```
        <dl class="dl-horizontal hours">
            <dt data-day="1">Monday</dt> 
                <dd data-day="1">17:30 - 11:30</dd>
            <dt data-day="2">Tuesday</dt> 
                <dd data-day="2">17:30 - 11:30</dd>
            <dt data-day="3">Wednesday</dt> 
                <dd data-day="3">17:30 - 11:30</dd>
            <dt data-day="4">Thursday</dt> 
                <dd data-day="4">17:30 - 11:30</dd>
            <dt data-day="5">Friday</dt> 
                <dd data-day="5">17:30 - Midnight</dd>
            <dt data-day="6">Saturday</dt> 
                <dd data-day="6">17:30 - Midnight</dd>
            <dt data-day="0">Sunday</dt> 
                <dd data-day="0">17:30 - 11:30</dd>
        </dl>
```

JS

```
    today=new Date();
    thisDay=today.getDay();
    $('[data-day='+thisDay+']').addClass('current')();
```

This does add the `.current` to the correct day but I get a JS error

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

which breaks all JS after those lines.

Could someone explain what is wrong here and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$('[data-day='+thisDay+']').addClass('current')();
```

to

```
$('[data-day='+thisDay+']').addClass('current');
```

the last set of parentheses is trying to execute the jQuery object, which is not a function

Answer (score 2):

Last line should be like this:

```
$('[data-day='+thisDay+']').addClass('current');
//without () in the end
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!